# Is there a way to turn an obj into a partial shrink wrap for another obj to deform into?

Tags: modeling, modifiers

As you can see in the image below, I have two faces. One with a complete head, and another as just the face. I'm trying to deform the one with a complete head to match that of the 'face'. Shrink wrap doesn't work as it just causes the entire head to shrink into the mask and I cannot combine it as the mesh for the head cannot be deleted/merged as I plan to use it as a morph target in Daz3d. Any help would be appreciated. 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Shrinkwrap contains a vertex group field. Just assign the needed vertices in a group, and specify this group in the shrinkwrap modifier.

Comment: How do you group said vertices? And also, sorry to bother, but how do you select the vertices accurately? Does it have to be done by eye?

Comment: To create a group : go to the properties panel and the data tab. and below click + on the vertex groups. Then back to 3D view go to edit mode on the complete head. Then yes, select the vertices accurately and assign them to the group.

Comment: @BlenderScrub You can also go straight into weight paint mode after creating the group and mirror paint the vertex group.